# Buttons on an old non-scientific calculator are less sensitive

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

> All 5 numbers are entered in an ascending order.
>   These numbers are in an arithmetic progression.
>   The value of the fifth number, i.e. the largest number, is less than 99.
>   While adding these numbers, two plus(+) symbols were accidentally not entered due to the bad calculator, giving the sum as **71157**.
>   And while finding the product of these numbers, two multiplication symbols were not typed, resulting in the mistaken product as **11698071**.
>   In the places where + were entered correctly in the first operation, multiplication symbols were missing there in second operation and vice versa.

**Find those 5 numbers, if the digit at the tens place of second number is 1.**

Comment: It took me 2 days to correctly frame this puzzle.

Answer (score 11):

**This first part is the answer to the original incorrectly stated question**

It seems to me only one of the multiplications is missing:

> $2221065 = 3^2*5*7*11*641 = 7*11*15*1923$
>
>  $71157 = 71115+19+23$
>  
> I found this by looking at the factorisation, and seeing the large prime 641. It did not seem like the concatenation of two successive numbers in an arithmetic sequence, so then I tried combining it with a factor 3 to get 1923. This looked more promising as a concatenation of 19 and 23, and extending that sequence produced my answer.

**This part is the answer to the corrected question**

> $11698071 = 3*7*11*89*569 = 7*11*151923$
>
>  $71157 = 71115+19+23$
>
> This is just a variation of the previous answer.
>  
> You can however reason about it as follows. The largest number has no more than 2 digits. The sum has 5 digits so the two missing plus symbols are consecutive to make a number from three of the items. This means that the smallest item has only one digit, so it is 7 to make the first digit of the sum correct. The next largest item must be 10 or 11 because of the next two digits of the sum. So the sequence is 7/10/13/16/19 or 7/11/15/19/23. The second is then easily found to be the correct one because 71013+16+19 gives the wrong sum. Note that I didn't even need to use the product to find the answer.

Comment: I arrived at the same conclusion using the same method.  I was trying to find a solution to the problem as stated but I think that, like you, I'm now inclined to believe the problem is incorrect.

Comment: I found this solution too but since OP said he spent two days working on this problem I kept digging. It doesn't look like there are solutions for the puzzle as it is right now.

Comment: I am debuting here with this question. I am amateur, but I don't find question have any shortcoming.

Comment: I have verified that there are no solutions with two digit numbers.

Comment: @NikhilBhavar After a while, if nobody has got the correct answer, perhaps you should post it. If you do, please wait at least 48 hours (2 days).

Comment: He has found the right numbers. Just the way, it is found is a shortcut.

Comment: @NikhilBhavar In your question you write that two additions are missing and that two multiplications are missing. In my answer there is only one multiplication missing.

Comment: You are right. I edited it. Sorry. Amateur.

Comment: To the corrected answer: I stated, the digit at tens place of second number is 1 not at units place. I haven't edited this now. This information was present from beginning.

Comment: @NikhilBhavar You're right, I misread that part of the question. It isn't needed for the solution anyway so I've edited my answer.

Comment: I believe you will find there are three other non-negative possible sequences, neither of which gives the correct sum.  These are the sequences with seven as the second or third number.

Answer (score 2):

> Let the numbers be $a, a+b, a+2b, a+3b$ and $a+4b$. If we assume $b=0$, then $a<11$ based on the wrong product. Even where numbers are concatenated, the concatenated number's mod 9 value is equivalent to the sum of the initial numbers, so the the sum being wrong doesn't make a difference in this aspect. The wrong sum can be written as $9k+3$, meaning the average ($a+2b$) must be written as $9k+6$. Since the digit of ones of $a+4b$ is the last ever digit in the multiplication, it must be odd, making also $a$ and $a+2b$ odd. $a$ can only be an odd digit. According to the last sentence in the question, $a+b$ must have multiple digits. 71157 must be the sum of 3 terms, so at least one of them has 5 digits. Since $a+b > (a+4b)/4$, $a+4b$ can have one digit more than $a+b$ at most. If $a+b$ has $d$ digits, $2d<6$, $d<3$, so $d$ can only be 2 and $a+b$ is a two-digit number whose digit of tens is 1. Even $a+4b$ has 2 digits. A 5-digit number can only be formed by concatenating *three* consecutive numbers, with the first being a single-digit number ($a$ that is). 
>  The remaining terms in the addition are the last two numbers, whose sum is less than 199, making the $a$ in the 5-digit number 7.
>  $a+b$ starts with 1, which becomes the digit of thousands of the 5-digit number. That means $a+3b+a+4b = 2a+7b < 158$ 
> That 5-digit number ends with $a+2b$, an odd 2-digit number that can be written as $9k+6$ whose digit of ones is at most 3. May be 15 or 33, but the latter means $a+b=20$, so $a+2b=15$ and $b=4$.

Solution:

> The numbers are 7, 11, 15, 19 and 23. The addition is $71115+19+23=71157$ and the multiplication is $7*11*151923=11698071$.

Comment: Why was this downvoted despite being neither wrong nor a duplicate? Personal grudges much?

Comment: Haters gonna hate.

Comment: I haven't voted yet.

Comment: I didn't get: "Even where numbers are concatenated, the concatenated number's mod 9 value is equivalent to the sum of the initial numbers, so the the sum being wrong doesn't make a difference in this aspect."

Comment: Can you explain with an example.

Comment: The mod 9 value is the mod 9 value of the sum of digits, so the remainder from divising by 9 won't change if the digits have gone nowhere. Take 37+48. 37 is 1 (mod 9) and 48 is 3 (mod 9). The sum is 4 (mod 9), but that can be directly worked out by adding up all the digits in the addition: 3+7+4+8 = 22 (mod 9) ie. 4 (mod 9).