# The old calculator v2

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

This is related to the question asked before: [Buttons on an old non-scientific calculator are less sensitive](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51601/buttons-on-an-old-non-scientific-calculator-are-less-sensitive)

We have chosen 5 different integer values ($a,b,c,d,e$), and written them in an ascending order next to each other and taken their sum and multiplication. Strangely, we got the same result as $41040$ after the multiplication and summation.

Then we noticed that it was actually our mistake while calculating their sum, our old calculator did not get the input "+" twice in a row while putting values to the calculator at some point but there was no mistake at multiplication.

What are our numbers?

Comment: Thanks for fine tuning the question. I am loving this place(stackexchange). People are so intelligent and admirable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbers are

> 3, 4, 10, 18, 19

Prime factorization got us to

> $2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 19$, addition rules implied that the numbers that were combined started with 4,10 and tweaking results got me the rest of the way.